# How to get rid of scrollbars around iframe

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe

Hi I use `iframe`for my facebook apps. The iframe gets a scrollbar around itself. Can you tell me how to avoid getting the scrollbar around the iframe? I currently have 2 facebook apps as iframes and one of them gets scrollbars that it shouldn't have:

http://apps.facebook.com/cyberfaze/ (has scrollbars or scroll areas around iframe that I don't want)
http://apps.facebook.com/koolbusiness/ (same CSS and has no scrollbars)

Could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your application settings on Facebook

you will find **canvas settings**

In the canvas settings you will find **IFrame Size:**

You will find two options

1. Show scrollbars
2. Auto-resize

select Auto-resize to get rid of from the scroll bars.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to go to your app settings -> canvas settings -> iFrame size (as mentioned by Micheal) and set it to auto-resize.

You will also need to make sure you have `body, html { overflow: hidden; }` for you iframe content

Then the below will help, chuck that in and change your app id -

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxxxxx',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
        //this resizes the the i-frame
        //on an interval of 100ms
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(100);
    };

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);  
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I got it working just by changing to Auto-resize

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting in the Facebook Developers App Setup section to set scrolling to `Auto-resize`. and you can add to your CSS file : `html { overflow:hidden; }`

[image]

Comment: +1 for your info. I try to keep a minimal CSS and neither `overflow:hidden`nor any change of javascript was required. `Auto-rezise`completely and conveniently arranged my ifram the way I wanted.

Comment: :) Thx. Yess the css option is optional. I had a issue where my app was restricted by height, and the Auto-Resize added a v-scroller even though the image used was exactly the same dimensions.. just a fail-safe. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have forgot to set the iframe scrolling attribute to "no"?

Try to change the iframe tag to this:

```
<iframe class="smart_sizing_iframe noresize" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe_canvas" name="iframe_canvas" src='javascript:""' height="600px" style="height: 719px; overflow-y: hidden; ">
```

Hope this was what you where looking for!

Comment: I don't control this variable though it might be indirectly controlled via changing a variable from facebook to auto-resize which solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Usually with iframes you can either use the CSS method setting `overflow: hidden` or you can use the scrolling attribute of the iframe and set it to `scrolling="no"`.

Having looked at your examples though, I am not sure that is what is causing your issue. Facebook iframes have their own set of issues.

First go to the devloper app and edit your app settings. In the Facebook Integration area set *iframe size* to *auto-resize*. Then in your app, after FB.init, call FB.Canvas.setAutoResize. Here is a link about [FB.Canvas.setAutoResize](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoResize/).

Comment: Thank you! Setting it to auto-resize was all I needed.